# Symfony: error while joining 2 tables to fetch values in seperate columns

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to fetch 3 values, 2 from a table name 'sales' and 1 from a table named 'products', I wrote following DQL:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:Sales');
        $q = $repo->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select('s.units','s.timestamp','p.price')
            ->join('SystemBundle:Product', 'p')
            ->where('s.prodId = p.id AND p.company=:comp')
            ->setParameter('comp', $cid)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
        return new JsonResponse($q);
```

but I am getting this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 81 near 'SystemBundle:Product': Error: Class 'SystemBundle\Entity\Product' is not defined.

It my first time working with joins in doctrine, so I guess I am messing with syntax here.. please help solving this

thanks

Comment: Does Sales have a relation to Product? If so the join should be '->join('s.products', 'p');' where "products" is the name you've set as the relation name. and the prodId = id part of the where should be skipped

Comment: Why didn't you fetching the result with doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With doctrine methods you can fetching the result that you need:

```
$productRepository = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:Product');
$oProduct = $productRepository->findBy(array('company' => $cid));

$oCompany = $oProduct->getCompany();

$result = array(
    'units' => $oCompany->getUnits(),
    'timestamp' => $oCompany->getTimestamp(),
    'price' => $oProduct->getPrice(),
);

$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData($result);

return $response;
```